# Cocos2d-x AudioTrack error playing sound effect

Tags: android, audio, cocos2d-x

I had a sound effect in my Cocos2d-x game that played everytime I touched a block in my game

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect("dig.mp3");
```

At the beginning the sound played with no problems, but now it doesn't and I get these messages from LogCat:

```
D/AudioTrack(15324): audiotrack 0x535df530 set Type 3, rate 44100, fmt 1, chn 3, fcnt 4096, flag 4
D/AudioTrack(15324): audiotrack 0x535df530 stop done
```

My code still the exact same way like before, so I don't know what is really hapenning.

The file is in the Resources folder and has no problems...

Comment: you should not use mp3 for short sound effects, very inefficient. Try wav or caf instead.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D it just stopped playing again, I just don't get it :(